# searching an exact number of files in a Linux directory

Tags: linux, find

I want recursively count files in a Linux directory  using this

```
find DIR_NAME -type f | wc -l
```

my question is , how to stop the find execution above if more than 1000 files are found in that folder ?
Is it possible ? Or do I need to wait find execution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `head` to limit the number of lines returned by find:

```
find DIR_NAME -type f | head -n 1000 | wc -l
```

The `head` program will exit after the first thousand lines, `find` will receive SIGPIPE and exit as well.